# Function equals in calculator

Tags: ios, swift, calculator, equals-operator

I'm new to Swift programming using Xcode. I created an application that is much similar to the calculator in Windows 7 (default calculator). I'm having a problem with the equals @IBAction button. In Windows 7 calculator, each number that executes the operation

like:

```
2*2 = 4
```

That will be the result and if you click the button " = " consecutively it will execute the operation and the second input would multiply the result so it would be something like this.

```
//WINDOWS 7 CALCULATOR OUTPUT

4 // this is the result
//if user press equals consecutively
4, 8 , 16 , 32 , 64
//and so on, this is how the windows 7 calcu executes the equals button
```

In my code I'm having the problem of it. When I press equals it will multiply the result consecutively.

Example:

```
//MY CALCULATOR OUTPUT IN XCODE

2 * 2 = 4 //result is four

//If equals is click consecutively the result would be this
4 , 16 , 256 , 65536 // and so on

//so basically it will multiply the result of calculator's result.
```

So, **what I'm actually aiming here is to have the same/similar result as the windows 7 calculator**. How do I perform this kind of method? Do I have to declare a temporary variable that will hold the second number input?

This is my code so far:

I created a class called MyCalculator.swift

**MY CALCULATOR**

```
//
//  MyCalculator.swift
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by
//  Anonymous
//

import Foundation

class MyCalculator
{
    var memory: Float = 0

    var percentnum: Float = 0

    var currentNum: Float = 0

    var result: Float = 0

    var operation: String = ""

    var isOperation: Bool = false

    var isRepeatOperation: Bool = false

    var isNum: Bool = false

    func operation (operation:String) -> Float
    {
        if operation == "+" {
            result = result + currentNum
        }
        else if operation == "-" {
            result = result - currentNum
        }
        else if operation == "*" {
            result = result * currentNum
        }
        else if operation == "/" {
            result = result / currentNum
        }
        return result
    }

    func percent(percentNum:Float) ->Float
    {
        let valpercent = percentNum * 0.01
        result = result * valpercent
        return result
    }

    func clearAll() {
        result = 0
        currentNum = 0
        isNum = false

    }

}
```

and this is my ViewController.swift file

**VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by 
//  Anonymous
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Start Calculator

    //Declerations      

    //Label Result: This is where the result is displayed
    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!


    //Initialization
    let calc = MyCalculator() //call the class MyCalculator

    //Function for Number Inputs
    @IBAction func btnNumInput(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let num = sender.currentTitle 
        if calc.isNum == false
        {
            lblResult.text = num
            calc.isNum = true
        }
        else
        {
            lblResult.text = lblResult.text! + num!!
        }
        calc.isRepeatOperation = false
    }

    //Function for Equals
    @IBAction func btnEquals(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        calc.currentNum = Float(lblResult.text!)!
        lblHistory.text = ""
        calc.isNum = false

        if calc.operation == "+"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("+")
        }
        else if calc.operation == "-"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("-")
        }
        else if calc.operation == "*"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("*")
        }
        else if calc.operation == "/"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("/")
        }

        if calc.operation == "/" && calc.currentNum == 0
        {
            lblResult.text = "Cannot divide by zero"
            calc.result = 0
        }
        else
        {
            let stringresult = String(format:"%g" , calc.result)
            lblResult.text = "\(stringresult)"
            calc.isOperation = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the top of the `btnEquals` action, you update the value of property `currentNum` to the most current result. In your operation method in the MyCalculator class, you compute new results as `result OP currentNum`, e.g. for OP=*, `results * currentNum?. Repeated "equals" action for user will result in the exponential behaviour you see, i.e., `result * currentNum` are, for repeated equal action, `result * result`. If you want the Windows calculator behaviour, you need to keep the "original" value of `currentNum` as long as user don`t enter a new operation or new operand.

Comment: The operation is always performed with `result` and `currentNum`. At the beginning of the operation `currentNum` is set to `result`. (2 * 2 = 4 * 4 = 16 * 16 = 256 etc.) You need an additional variable `operand` to keep the right side of the operation (2 * 2 = 4 * 2 = 8 * 2 = 16)

Comment: BTW, you do minus for the "*" operator.

Comment: And you can get rid of lots of the if-else stuff by using `calc.result = calc.operation(calc.operation)` As this looks funny you should consider renaming one of the `operation` things. You have a local variable and a function using the same name. That may work but is rather "smelly" .

Comment: @vadian so I need to add another variable that will hold the currentNum?  Could you provide a simple code that corresponds to your explanation sir? If you may.

Comment: your if-else logic is a perfect situation for a switch statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will solve

```
func btnEquals(sender: AnyObject)
{
 if (!calc.isRepeatOperation) {  //New Code
    calc.currentNum = Float(lblResult.text!)!
 } 
 lblHistory.text = ""
 calc.isNum = false
 //.....
 else {
        let stringresult = String(format:"%g" , calc.result)
        lblResult.text = "\(stringresult)"
        calc.isOperation = false
        calc.isRepeatOperation = true  //New Code
    }
```

}

The reason is the currentValue is overwritten from the result label.
Repeated equalTo should perform the result operation with the previousValue.

2*2 = 4 = 8 =16

4*2 = 8 = 16 = 32

16/4 = 4 = 1 = 0.25

Comment: Oh, this one is correct sir. I didn;t know that boolean is also helpful in situation like this. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need some temporary variable to store multiplier, currently what you're doing:

```
func operation (operation:String) -> Float
    {
        ...
        else if operation == "*" {
            // I suppose this is typo? and there is actualy * instead of "-"?
            result = result - currentNum  
        }
        ...
    }
```

So you had:

```
2*2 = 4
```

And after that both `result` and `currentNum` have value 4. So it goes like this:

```
4*4 = 16
// result, currentNum = 16
16*16 = 256
```

Proper way would be something like this:

```
else if operation == "*" {                    
    result = currentNum * multiplier  
}
```

Comment: Using this proper way you've mention, does it operates consecutively sir?

Comment: It doesn't? Should be ok if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I really don't know why you use Float instead of Double, but most people will be very unhappy with a calculator that doesn't even provide 8 digits precision.

Comment: @gnasher729 was it meant to me? I was just showing laurence's code

Comment: No need to argue, I'm just focusing the equals for function for this moment. Though it's a good advice to change the data type to double. I'll take note of that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is: You use lblResult to show result value, and use lblResult.text for the next calculation.

Your calc.currentNum is overwritten with your result.
You have to use a variable to store result and another for input values then problem will be solved :)